# create HTML table from an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create two separate tables on success of an ajax call. am getting the JSON data in the following format

```
                {
  "id" : "AgeGroups",
  "simpleFields" : {
    "STATE" : "Master",
    "NUM_PARTITIONS" : "12",
  },
  "listFields" : {
  },
  "mapFields" : {
    "Agegroup1" : {
      "Name1" : "10",
      "Name2" : "15",
      "Name3" : "18"
    },
    "AgeGroup2" : {
      "Name1" : "21",
      "Name1" : "25",
      "Name1" : "27"
    },
```

so the first table i need only `id,state` and `NUM_PARTITIONS`.. And second table i need all Agegroups.. Is ther any way i can do it?
  I tried the following...but not sure how to do for 2 table

Tried this

```
              $('<table>').html(
              "<thead> " +
                      "<tr>" +
                      "<th> <strong> ID </strong>  </th>" +
                      "<th> <strong> State </strong></th> " +
                      "<th> <strong> NumPartitons </strong></th>" +
                      "</r> </thead>" +
                      " <tbody>" +
                      " <tr>" +
                      "<td>" + response.ID + "</td>" +
                      "<td>"+response.State +"</td>" +
                      "<td>"+ response.Partitons +"</td> " +
                      "</tr>" +
                      "</tbody>" +
                      "</table>"
    ).appendTo('#resulttable');
```

Comment: Why not write some Javascript? Seems the obvious solution.

Comment: ... please can we have the option that the questioner has tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

For first table,

```
$('<table>').html(
        "<thead> " +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th> <strong> ID </strong>  </th>" +
        "<th> <strong> State </strong></th> " +
        "<th> <strong> NumPartitons </strong></th>" +
        "</r> </thead>" +
        " <tbody>" +
        " <tr>" +
        "<td>" + response.id + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.simpleFields.STATE + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.simpleFields.NUM_PARTITIONS + "</td> " +
        "</tr>" +
        "</tbody>" +
        "</table>"
        ).appendTo('#resulttable');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Weg7w/3/)

For creating second table

```
var a = "";
$.each(response.mapFields, function() {
    a += (" <tr>" +
            "<td>" + this.Name1 + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + this.Name2 + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + this.Name3 + "</td> " +
            "</tr>");
});
$('<table>').html(
        "<thead> " +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th> <strong> Name1</strong>  </th>" +
        "<th> <strong> Name2 </strong></th> " +
        "<th> <strong> Name3 </strong></th>" +
        "</r> </thead>" +
        " <tbody>" +
        a
        +
        "</tbody>" +
        "</table>"
        ).appendTo('#resulttable');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7F5dW/)

Comment: This is only for one table...how i will create next?

Comment: @PranavCBalan excellent answer +1 for you

Comment: yea this works...sooper...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
window.response=[{
  "id" : "AgeGroups",
  "simpleFields" : {
    "STATE" : "Master",
    "NUM_PARTITIONS" : "12",
  },
  "listFields" : {
  },
  "mapFields" : {
    "Agegroup1" : {
      "Name1" : "10",
      "Name2" : "15",
      "Name3" : "18"
    },
    "AgeGroup2" : {
      "Name1" : "21",
      "Name1" : "25",
      "Name1" : "27"
    }
  }
}];
for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
$('<table>').html(
        "<thead> " +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th> <strong> ID </strong>  </th>" +
        "<th> <strong> State </strong></th> " +
        "<th> <strong> NumPartitons </strong></th>" +
        "</r> </thead>" +
        " <tbody>" +
        " <tr>" +
        "<td>" + response[i]['id'] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response[i]['simpleFields']['STATE'] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response[i]['simpleFields']['NUM_PARTITIONS'] + "</td> " +
        "</tr>" +
        "</tbody>" +
        "</table>"
        ).appendTo('#resulttable');

}
```

In your case, you need to follow the json syntax like this,

```
ID: response.id, STATE: response.simpleFields.STATE
```

Demo url http://jsfiddle.net/VxL8J/

Comment: This part i have done already. my question is how we can create the next table containing agegroups?

Comment: @user2144794 ok, try to send the mpaFields from server like this way `"mapFields" : [
    "Agegroup1" : {
      "Name1" : "10",
      "Name2" : "15",
      "Name3" : "18"
    },
    "AgeGroup2" : {
      "Name1" : "21",
      "Name1" : "25",
      "Name1" : "27"
    }
  ]`. So you can get this way response.mapFields.length.